# Can is_trivially_copy_assignable and is_trivially_copy_constructible be exploited for optimization purposes?

Tags: c++, c++11, memcpy, type-traits

It seems that values aren't safe to copy with `memcpy` unless the type is trivially copyable, i.e. satisfies the `std::is_trivially_copyable` type trait. I wonder what the purpose of the type traits `std::is_trivially_copy_assignable`, `std::is_trivially_copy_constructible`, `std::is_trivially_move_assignable` and `std::is_trivially_move_constructible` is if you can't exploit them for initialization or assignment with `memcpy`. Do they permit other optimizations?

I also wonder why the standard requires a trivial destructor for values to be copyable with `memcpy`. (A trivial destructor does simplify physically moving a value in memory, but it doesn't seem to be fundamentally necessary for just duplicating a value with `memcpy`).

Comment: Imagine that the destructor does some work (anything). If you just copy (bitwise), then you know have two objects that will do this work when their destructor is run. Obviously, the type should have a non-trivial copy-constructor to begin with, but this check on the destructor can be seen as a last resort measure :)

Comment: If you actually want to duplicate a value, then you would expect the destructor to eventually run twice. Also, if you manually manage the allocation and freeing, e.g. in a container class, you could just omit  the destructor call on the original value before freeing or reusing the memory.

Answer (score 3):

> I wonder what the purpose of the type traits `std::is_trivially_copy_assignable`, `std::is_trivially_copy_constructible`, `std::is_trivially_move_assignable` and `std::is_trivially_move_constructible` if you can't exploit them for initialization or assignment with `memcpy`

They tell you properties of the type, isn't that enough reason to exist?

You might have a type which has a trivial copy constructor but a non-trivial move constructor, so it would not qualify as a trivially copyable type, but is trivially-copy-constructible.

When using such a type you could use SFINAE or other static polymorphism to enable/disable certain operations unless they're guaranteed to be trivial.  For example imagine a class template `TrivialPair<A,B>` which could declare its move constructor as deleted if `A` and `B` are not trivially move constructible, and similarly for the other operations. That would mean that `TrivialPair` only supports operations which `A` and `B` both support and which don't call any non-trivial functions.

> I also wonder why the standard requires a trivial destructor for values to be copyable with `memcpy`

"Trivially copyable" can be thought of as saying the type is just a bunch of bytes, i.e. just data that can be copied to another place in memory safely and without altering the value. If the type has a non-trivial destructor then it's not just a bunch of bytes, it has some additional behaviour which the compiler doesn't comprehend, and which might make using `memcpy` unsafe.

Comment: I'm just curious whether there is any use for knowing whether individual methods (copy constructor, assignment operator, etc.) are trivial. When a type is trivially copyable (i.e. satisfies "is_trivially_copy") or when it is guaranteed not to throw an exception, you can use that for optimizations, but why would you want to define a type like your `TrivialPair` type?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. One could write a vector class template that exploits this and invokes std::memcpy in its copy constructor in case it's safe to do so. I believe at least one implementations of std::copy employs a similar optimization for the case when the iterators are of type T* and T is trivially copyable.

Comment: Does the standard actually permit copying with `memcpy` if a class e.g. satisfies `std::is_trivially_copy_constructible` and `std::is_trivially_copy_assignable` but not `std::is_trivially_copyable`? Or what does your "Sure." refer to?

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that this is just like any other nitpick in the standard. Somewhere out there Joe and Jane will be talking about how a char is 8 bits, and Bob will come in yelling about how the standard says it's actually "8 or MORE bits!" The next day they'll be doing doing some type punning hackery by copying a float into a uint32_t and doing some bit twiddling based on IEEE-754, and Bob will come in again yelling about how IEEE-754 isn't strictly required, and he'll insist that the bit twiddling they're doing might cause some theoretical machine out there to implode the universe.

Damn it Bob!

In practice it's plainly obvious that std::is_trivially_copy_assignable means that the expression "A = B" will just evaluate to a memcpy(), so go ahead and take advantage. Sure there might be some obscure implementation out there which goes out of it's way to give you the finger when you memcpy() a type that isn't strictly std::is_trivially_copyable, and I'm sure Bob is probably the author of said implementation, but do you really care?

This is just my guess, mind you. I have some moderate experience in this area, but I'm by no means a world class expert in C++ minutiae. If I'm wrong on this (in practice, not just in theory) then please feel free to let me know. I'd also love to see a machine with CHAR_BIT > 8 (which I would actually care about), or a machine with non IEEE-754 floats (again, which I would actually care about).